“I have lived in New York for 5 years” can it also mean I don’t live there anymore?
If I say “I have lived in New York for 5 years”, does it necessarily mean I still live there or can it also refer to the past without specifying a time reference?
I’ll explain better, if we don’t specify the duration, we generally say “I have lived in New York” to mean we’ve lived there in the past, now we don’t live there anymore, but “when” is not necessary in our message. If we do specify when then we’d use the past simple tense (I lived in New York in 2010). The present perfect continuous tense, in this case, would certainly mean I still live in New York, stressing the action and its duration “I’ve been living in New York”.
The problem arises when we put a duration:
If I say “I lived in New York for 5 years” I know I don’t live there anymore as it happened in the past and the action is over;
If I say “I have lived in New York for 5 years” I would think I still live there, and that I’m focusing on the result (example:
A: that bar is on 7th street!
B: no, it’s on 10th street!
A: listen, I’ve lived here for 5 years, I know where it is)
Maybe if I say “I have lived here for 5 years” implies I still live in the place, while if I say “I have lived there for 5 years” implies that I don’t live there anymore? If this is true, then “I have lived in New York for five years” would mean both, and we would only need the context to know for sure.

“I have lived in New York for five years” implies that you still do. "I lived in NY for five years" - you no longer do.

How did this Question sneak into Linguistics, or even English Language Usage, please?
Kate Bunting said all there is to be said.
